# Diffusion Equation Relation with Initial Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I am looking for some direction for some theorems which may help me. I'm currently developing a new type of solver (so far only for the basic heat equation) one issue i'm facing is that as you may expect the solution quality degrades as t increases.

What I am looking for is a theorem (if there is such a thing, which I so far haven't found) that relates the solution $u(x,t)$ to the initial boundary condition of $u(x,0)$. The idea is then I can use this as a measure of the accuracy of my approximation at $u(x,t)$.

Assume the problem in the domain $x = [0,1],\, t=[0,1]$ of the form

$u_t =u_{xx} ;$

$u(x,0) = f(x);$

$u(0,t) = 0;$

$u(1,t) = 0;$

Thanks
p.s. I am primarily and computer scientist so sorry if this question seems stupid!

Comment: What's the domain? If it's bounded, what are the spatial boundary conditions?

Comment: Hi Ian, at the moment just assume of simple neumann BC u(x,t) = 0 for x = 0, 1 at all t. The Initial condition is a generic function f(x).

Comment: Did you mean Dirichlet? In this simple 1D case there is actually an explicit solution, given using separation of variables. The initial condition is related to the solution through its Fourier coefficients. In the homogeneous Dirichlet case ($u(a)=u(b)=0$), these Fourier coefficients are all sine coefficients.

Comment: Hi Ian, yes I am using this as an example to test my solver algorithm so I can compare my numerical results to the analytical result.

Comment: OK. Well, in just this simple case, you can proceed more or less analytically, except for doing some integrals numerically. That's because you have the explicit solution, which is (up to some missing $\pi$'s and $2$s, which you should either work out yourself or look up) $u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-n^2t} \sin(n \pi x)$ where $a_n = \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(n \pi x) dx$. But this approach will not help you in even slightly more general problems.

Comment: the idea is that I am looking for something which doesn't assume any knowledge of the solution, so I can use this as a refinement procedure in my algorithm. The method I am using approximates the close form solution at collocation points in the domain, I'm looking for some kind of "anchoring" of my solution at the collocation points to the IBC

Comment: which is why I am not sure such a theorem exists

Comment: You will either need some idea of the solution or else some strong restrictions on the class of problems you wish to solve in order to do any such thing. For instance you could have an equation which quickly approaches some regime (maybe an equilibrium or something) regardless of the initial condition.

Comment: is there not a reverse time stepping procedure i could do?

Comment: Reverse time stepping is generally ill-defined in PDEs. (In particular it is ill-defined for the heat equation. You *can* in theory go backward in time from a solution which has already gone forward in time, but this should be expected to be very numerically unstable.)

Comment: hmmm i see, maybe this isn't possible :(. At each point I know dt, dxx and the approximation v(x,t). But thanks for your help!